# Can square matrices be represented as the union of vectors and some other set?

Tags: matrices

I believe all invertible matrices can be representable as $A = |A| \, \mathrm{adj}\left(A\right)^{-1}$ (a rotation part times a scaling part.)

All invertible matrices can then be mapped to vectors with $\vec{x} = A \hat{e}_0$ for some vector of unit length $\hat{e}_0$.

I believe all vectors (except for the zero value) can then be mapped to invertible matrices but I'm not sure of the exact algorithm.

Then all matrices can be represented as

$\mathrm{M}^n = \left\{0\right\} \cup \mathrm{R}^n \setminus \left\{0\right\}  \cup X$

where $X$ is the set of all degenerate matrices but that I'm not sure how to represent.

Answer (score 0):

Really it is not at all what you think. An invertible matrix in general does not rotate and scale a vector it multiplies in a way that is indipendent of the vector itself.
So you cannot take as a representative of an invertible matrix the result of the multiplication of the matrix by a reference vector. Immagine an invertible real matrix not equal to the identity matrix having as an eigenvector the vector you have chosen as a reference, and suppose that this eigenvector has $1$ as the associated eigenvalue. What you want to choose as a representative for such a matrix would be equal to what you want to choose as a representative of the identity matrix. So the trick does not work. Only certain subsets of the set of matrices can be thought to work the way you think. As an instance one of them it is the set of $2x2$ real matrix that have no real eigenvalues or have real eigenvalues of multiplicity $2$ and the $2x2$ null matrix. Such matrices are really mappable to vectors of the real plane using the method you said. In addition you have not to deal with particular degenerate matrices, the only one being the null matrix that's mapped to the zero vector. These matrices and the vectors they are mapped to are better known as complex numbers.